# JavaScript arrays undefined after pushing onto another array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm writing some JavaScript that will eventually display a tarot spread. Right now, I'm having trouble with a two dimensional array of cards, two dimensions because I need to keep track of the orientation of the cards.

Part of the file so far:

```
const DeckSize = "78";

function TarotCard(cardNumber, isInverse){
  card=new Array();
  card.push(cardNumber);
  card.push(isInverse);
console.log("new card="+card[0]+" "+card[1]);
}

function TarotDeck(){
  deck=new Array();

  for(i=0; i<DeckSize; i++){
    deck.push(new TarotCard(i, false));
console.log("pushed new card as "+deck[i][0]+" and "+deck[i][1]);
  }
console.log(deck.length);
  return shuffleDeck(deck, 3);
}
```

The console.log lines give this:

> new card=0 false pushed as undefined and undefined

...78 times, of course. I'm not sure where things are going wrong.

Comment: Your `TarotCard` function doesn't return a value.

Comment: D'oh. Yeah, that got it. Thanks.

And yes, I need the inversion later in some readings.